# Mips Stack Pointer can't reach next stack value

Tags: stack, mips, stack-pointer

i'm trying to do a program in mars that , using $sp, can jump to the next address of the stack and read the value:

```
fine_while:

add $a0, $S,$a2
li $v0, 1
syscall
move  $t5, $sp#indirizzo iniziale
move $sp, $t6 #indiirzzi di -51
subi  $sp, $sp, 4 #shifto di una podizione il sp ora come se 2 fosse quello iniziale.probabilmente i negativ occupano + byte
lw $a2, ($sp)
move $t6, $sp #e lo pongo uguale ad a2 #ATTENZIONE! qui stai ponendo il ad a2 l'indirizzo!!!
move $sp, $t5#riprsitino l sp
#incremenro sp di 4 per prepararmk ad immagazinare 4
#chiamare un nuobo elmeneto (4) e mettilo 
li $v0 , 5
syscall 
move $a1, $v0 
subi  $sp, $sp, 4 
sw $a1,($sp)
beqz $a1 , end  
sub $S, $S,$a2 #qui difatti stai sottraendo l indirzzo e non il contenuto...
add $S,$S, $a1
j fine_while
```

this is only a piece of source cause there are another operations( i have a sequence of numbers and i saved its into the stack) , the problem is that in a particoular time when i jump to next  stack address to reach the next number mips says that this cell is equal to zero, but why? in the cell there is a number that i allocated , right? but it's like it s empty, why? thank you

Comment: What is `$S`? And why are you moving back and forth between `$sp` and `$t6`? There are plenty of available registers you can use. Also, please comment your code in english so that it can be understood by others.

Comment: simply , i have a sequence like that : 1, 2,3,4,5,6  saved on the stack, now $sp point to "6" address, now i want to jump to "2" address that i saved in a register before, but why when i point to next address ( "3") programm give me "0" as value of ($sp)?

Comment: I still don't understand those unncessary moves. And you've only showed us part of the code, so it's impossible for anyone else than you so see what you've might done wrong in the rest of the code. In any case, the way you would find the bug(s) is to use the debugging features in the simulator. Set breakpoints at places of interest in the code, and single-step from there until the value of any register or memory location differs from what it should be.